# Attempting to alter the colour of a TextView at runtime, text "disappears"

Tags: android

I'm trying to alter the properties of a TextView at run time, and one of the things I'm trying to do is to alter the text colour when the user presses a button, however when the user presses the button the text simply "disappears".

```
    // Changes colour of team name text when a colour button is pressed 
    bColourPink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvTeamName.setTextColor(R.color.pink); 
        }
    });
```

The colour resource is working as intended in other areas of the program (i.e. displaying the intended colour correctly).

In researching the problem I found someone else had the same issue because their colour resources were #rgb so it was setting the alpha as 0, however I altered my colour resources to #aarrggbb format and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: today i have already passed half day for the color issue....was done with `Color.rgb()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use

tvTeamName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));

Comment: Thank you! :) (I should have seen something didn't look right!)

Answer (score 3):

`R.color.pink` is a value which represents the 'id' of the resource.
It is not the resource itself, so it is not the color pink.

Use `getResources()` to get the resource `R.color.pink`.